# How do you edit the literals when inserting a snippet into Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

When I am inserting a snippet into the source code the literals immediately get replaced with empty string and there is no prompt to enter a value for them. How do you insert a snippet to get prompt for the literals? For example here is a small snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>Test</Title>
      <Author>RM</Author>
      <Description>New Transaction</Description>
      <HelpUrl>
      </HelpUrl>
      <Shortcut>test</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>test</ID>
          <ToolTip>tool tip</ToolTip>
          <Default>Test
          </Default>
          <Function></Function>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp" Delimiter="$"><![CDATA[$test$

$test$

$test$$end$]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

UPDATE: I have updated the script as was suggested by adding a default value and $end$ however this is still not working. If I insert the snippet (using Ctrl-K, X) the default value is inserted. When I change one of the values only that one is changing but not the others.

[image]

Comment: It works for me. I type "test123" (i have another snippet called 'test'), write "hello" and press enter. I get three hello's

Comment: @FishySwede - this is actually the answer I was looking for. I haven't realized that I have to change the text and then press enter! If you add this as an answer I will accept it

Comment: Glad I could help. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the

```
<Default></Default>
```

to something. That is needed to give the snippet something to highlight for editing.
Also you should add

> $end$

at the end of the code part.

To get the text to update just enter your new text and press enter and all three variables should update.

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>Test</Title>
      <Author>RM</Author>
      <Description>New Transaction</Description>
      <HelpUrl>
      </HelpUrl>
      <Shortcut>test123</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>test</ID>
          <ToolTip>tool tip</ToolTip>
          <Default>test</Default>
          <Function></Function>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp" Delimiter="$"><![CDATA[$test$

$test$

$test$$end$]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```